# Subs en una lista python

Tags: python

Tengo un pequeño programa en Python que calcula 4 ecuaciones en base a una función y sus derivadas.

El problema viene cuando uso la solución de la primera ecuación y trato de sustituirla en otra ecuación. Obtengo el error de:

> el atributo list no es compatible con subs.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo realizar la modificación de las siguientes ecuaciones en función del primer resultado ?

Nota. el programa sigue después pero me interesa primero resolver este error que se concentra en las ultimas líneas.

```
import sympy as sp

g, a, A, C, D, K, x = sp.symbols("g a A C D K x")

X=(A*sp.cos(g*x/a))+(sp.sin(g*x/a))+(C*sp.exp(-g*x/a))+(D*sp.exp(-g*(a-x)/a))

dx1=sp.diff(X,x,1)

dx2=sp.diff(X,x,2)

eq1= sp.Eq(X.subs(x,0),0)
eq2= sp.Eq(dx2.subs(x,0)/dx1.subs(x,0),K)
eq3= sp.Eq(X.subs(x,a),0)
eq4= sp.Eq(dx2.subs(x,a)/dx1.subs(x,a),-K)

D1=sp.solve(eq1,D)
eq33=D1.subs(D,D1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema se encuentra en la línea:

```
eq33=D1.subs(A,D1)
```

Dónde `D1` lo obtienes en la línea anterior como `D1=sp.solve(eq1,D)`. El método `sp.solve` retorna una lista con las soluciones posibles a la ecuación. Para aplicar el método `subs` debes hacerlo sobre cada expresión de la lista y no sobre la lista:

```
D1=sp.solve(eq1,D)
eq33 = [expr.subs(D, expr) for expr in D1]
```

`eq33` es una lista de expresiones al igual que `D1`.

Un ejemplo donde se ve como `solve` retorna una lista con las soluciones y como subtituir un símbolo en todas ellas recorriendo esa lista :

```
>>> import sympy as sp    
>>> x, y = sp.symbols("x y")
>>> eq = (x**2 + 3*y + 42) 
>>> sol = sp.solve(eq,x)
>>> print(sol)
[-sqrt(-3*y - 42), sqrt(-3*y - 42)]
>>> sub = [expr.subs(y, expr) for expr in sol]
>>> print(sub)
[-sqrt(3*sqrt(-3*y - 42) - 42), sqrt(-3*sqrt(-3*y - 42) - 42)]
```

Puedes iterar, indexar, usar `list.pop()`, etc para obtener las expresiones de la lista. Si sabes seguro que `solve` **siempre** retorna **un sola** expresión como solución, puedes hacer simplemente:

```
eq33=D1[0].subs(D, D1[0])
```